# Using Linq to XML (C#) how do I find attribute values?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a simple XML file that looks something like:

```
<Institutions>
    <FI name = "NameOne">
        <longname>some text</longname>
        <APIKey>some text</APIKey>
        <connectstring>some text</connectstring>
    </FI>
    <FI name = "NameTwo">
        <longname>some text</longname>
        <APIKey>some text</APIKey>
        <connectstring>some text </connectstring>
    </FI>
</Institutions>
```

Using LINQ to XML I can grab the entire file, find all values for "longname", "APIKey" and "connectstring" but I can not figure out how to find all the "name" values or how to grab only the three pieces of information underneath each FI name value.  Just to be clear, I will have NO IDEA what the name= values are in advance.

I'm using:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("c:\\directory\\Data_Config.xml");
```

and

```
IEnumerable<XElement> Fis =
from el in root.Elements("Institutions")
select el;
```

to load the file, as per the MSDN documentation.  All of it's references seem to imply knowledge of what the name value is that I would be querying.

I've googled, tried different Attribute/Element queries, all with no luck.  I'm pretty sure it's something simple but it's evading me.

How do I get this data?

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var xml = XElement.Load (@"c:\directory\Data_Config.xml");
var query = 
    from e in xml.Descendants("FI")
    select e.Attribute("name").Value;
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  I'll select it once my 10 minute delay is up.